# Error on assigning an ACL in Oracle Database

Tags: xml, oracle, acl

**With the system user** (conn system/PASS)

I am trying to create and assingning an ACL in Oracle, but I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR line 1:
ORA-24244: INVALID HOST OR PORT FOR ACCESS CONTROL LIST (ACL) 
ORA-06512: em "SYS.DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN", line 1343
ORA-06512: em "SYS.DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN", line 724
ORA-06512: em line 2
```

The commands I am using are:

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.CREATE_ACL(acl         => 'www.xml',
                                    description => 'WWW ACL',
                                    principal   => 'HIGIIA',
                                    is_grant    => true,
                                    privilege   => 'connect');
END;
/
 BEGIN
  DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ADD_PRIVILEGE(acl       => 'www.xml',
                                       principal => 'HIGIIA',
                                       is_grant  => true,
                                       privilege => 'resolve');
END;
/
```

Everything ok until this point.

But when I try to assign the ACL with this command:

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ASSIGN_ACL(acl  => 'www.xml',
                                    host => 'https://appsonfire.000webhostapp.com/sample.xsd');
END;
/

ERROR line 1:
ORA-24244: INVALID HOST OR PORT FOR ACCESS CONTROL LIST (ACL) 
ORA-06512: em "SYS.DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN", line 1343
ORA-06512: em "SYS.DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN", line 724
ORA-06512: em line 2
```

What should I do to make it work?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

try  `select * from dba_network_acls` to see if there is an existing entry for the hostname.  Also, you many want to specify the upper/lower port values in the function call.